# Angular SweetAlert with directives and translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-directive, angular-translate

im currently using Angular implementation of the

[Sweet alert](https://github.com/oitozero/ngSweetAlert)

I want to pass to the title an Angular directive with translate

This is the variable I'm passing as title

```
{{ 'register.confirmation_modal.SUPERIOR_MESSAGE' | translate }}
```

And using [Angular Compile Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

```
var translate_title = "<span>{{ 'sa.title' | translate }}</span>";
var compiled_title = $compile(translate_title)($scope);
```

and using `html: true,` in Sweet alert options

But i'm getting an object and it's being printed like the follow image

[image]

I tried using .innerHTML but it removes the Tags and gets the literal string with the curly braces **{{ }}**

JSON.stringify didn't worked either.

Any advice?

Comment: I don't think this is quite the right way to handle translation inside a controller.  any time you have to use `$compile`, it has to be followed by a call to `$rootScope.$digest()` or `$scope.$apply()`, and generally calling these from a controller is very inefficient.  why not use `$filter('translate')('sa.title')` ?

Comment: Hi @Claies thanks for your feedback, It worked! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Credits to @Claies for pointing me to the solution

Instead of using `$compile` I solved my issue using the [Filter translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Getting-Started) from Angular translate

This did the trick:

```
var n = $filter('translate')('sa.title');
```

Regards.